# EmberJS Filter Returned Data from Store

Tags: ember.js, filter

I'm new to Ember and trying to figure out the best way to filter data with Ember. I thought it would be by creating either a helper or a component but my attempts at implementing these solutions have failed miserably.

Having read a lot about this today and tried several options my brain hurts and I am no closer to a result.

I'm building a schedule for an upcoming sports season. The template currently renders all games. The idea is when you click on a team name, you will see only games for that team. The data displayed is being stored in Firebase (so EmberFire).

The ability to also filter by date would also be nice but I figure that's a problem for future Red.

Sorry for the vagueness of my question, I know what it is I want to do I just no idea how to get there.

Thank you!
Red

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want to use a query parameter to specify the team to filter by.  In your `Controller`, specify the queryParams property and then create a computed property that returns the filtered list from the model:

```
queryParams: ['selectedTeam'],
selectedTeam: null,
filteredGames: Ember.computed('selectedTeam', 'model', function() {
  let selectedTeam= this.get('selectedTeam');
  let model= this.get('model');

  if (selectedTeam) {
    return model.filterBy('team', selectedTeam)
  }
  else {
    return model;
  }
```

Then, in your template, instead of using `model`, use `filteredGames`:

```
{{#each filteredGames as |game|}}
   ... render the {{game}} ...
{{/each}}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Steve! Your suggestion makes good sense, I'll have a run at it later on today :)

The Ember Guides for queryParams section Sticky Params might just solve the problem. I think I may need to change how my data is stored with its key: value pairings tho.